# Storing data from Android mobile into a Database

Tags: android, database

I am building an application where in I need to take the data (say inbox message) from an Android mobile phone store it in any database and then use the data from DB. Here I want the data from Android mobile to be directly stored in any DB. Can any one come out with a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the SQLite database in Android or send the data to a webservice, where you store the data in a database on the server.